# How to create an array with associative subarrays from a one-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have the following array.

```
Array(
[1041] => 30
[1046] => 10
[1047] => 10
)
```

and I want to store it like following.

```
Array([0] => Array
(
    [material_name] => 1041
    [material_qty] => 30
) 
[1] => Array
(
    [material_name] => 1046
    [material_qty] => 10
)
[2] => Array
(
    [material_name] => 1047
    [material_qty] => 10
) )
```

now i am trying to store key values but it stores only last one.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($materials); $i++){
              foreach($materials as $key => $value){
                 $dataArrMaterial[$i] = array(
                        'material_name' => $key,
              'material_qty' => $value
                         );
              } }
              _print($dataArrMaterial);
```

my output is follwoing.

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [material_name] => 1047
        [material_qty] => 10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [material_name] => 1047
        [material_qty] => 10
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [material_name] => 1047
        [material_qty] => 10
    ) )
```

now please help me do to that.
thanks in advance.

Comment: can you name the variables ? you put print_r output but we have to guess if it is $materials... or not. You should put PHP array declaration easy to copy paste and reproduce

Comment: change: foreach($materials as $key => $value){ to foreach($materials[$i] as $key => $value){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this quite a lot:

```
<?php
// ...
$dataArrMaterial = [];
foreach ($materials as $materialName => $materialQty) {
    $dataArrMaterial[] = [
        "material_name" => $materialName ,
        "material_qty" => $materialQty
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it wasn't explained to you *why*, I will.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($materials); $i++){
    foreach($materials as $key => $value){
        // the value of $i is not changed within this loop
        $dataArrMaterial[$i] = array('material_name' => $key, 'material_qty' => $value);
    }
    // when the for() loop starts again, $i is incremented
}
```

So, on the first iteration of the foreach loop, you are assigning all subarrays to the same `$i` key (`0`). After `1041` is looped, your output array looks like this:

```
[0 => ["material_name" => 1041, "material_qty" => 30]];
```

After `1046`, the first pushed subarray is overwritten because keys on the same level must be unique.

```
[0 => ["material_name" => 1046, "material_qty" => 10]];
```

Then the third element overwrites the second in the output array:

```
[0 => ["material_name" => 1047, "material_qty" => 10]];
```

Once the inner loop (`foreach`) is finished, the outer loop (`for`) increments `$i` and the "overwriting" process repeats for the `1` key of the output array.  And then again because `count($materials) = 3` (three iterations).

This is *why* you are getting the final set of values repeated like this:

```
[0 => ["material_name" => 1047, "material_qty" => 10]];
[1 => ["material_name" => 1047, "material_qty" => 10]];
[2 => ["material_name" => 1047, "material_qty" => 10]];
```

As for the best way to perform this task, you can use a solution from my duplicate link or do it as Arkascha has demonstrated.